# Drawable behaves differently in different activity layouts in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, button, android-drawable

I have the following drawable: `custom_yellow_button.xml` in the drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/yellow"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

and I have these two different layouts which both identically use the button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".LogInActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="275dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_yellow_button"
        android:fontFamily="@font/courierprime_regular"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:text="Log In"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        app:backgroundTintMode="add" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RegistrazioneActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="275dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_yellow_button"
        android:fontFamily="@font/courierprime_regular"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:text="Log In"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="21sp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In the first layout, it looks like this, which is how I want it :

[image]

while in the second layout, it looks like this:

[image].

Can anyone tell me why? I can provide more info if needed.

Comment: Can you remove this app:backgroundTintMode="add" and check if it still pink? If it does, could you post both layouts file?

Comment: If I do, it becomes purple. I am adding the layouts.

Comment: Could you please both layouts? the one with the yellow button and then the second one for the pink button?

Comment: please provide the full xml file.may be u have give parent layout some tint or color that is conflicting

Comment: I posted them, I removed some text fields which weren't relevant as the problem is not due to their presence on the layout

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what theme are you using, but with MaterialThemes you can do this and it's easy. First check this: https://material.io/components/buttons

Then, change your app theme to extend one of the material themes, like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Then add implementations:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
```

After that you can simply use this as your button inside your XML:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton/>
```

Inside this `View` you have a lot of attributes for your button. Simply check above link and see. For yours I would go with something like this:

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="60dp"
     android:textAlignment="center"
     android:textAllCaps="true"
     android:padding="15dp"
     android:backgroundTint="@color/yellow" //add background color
     app:rippleColor="@color/colorPrimary"  //ripple color - when button is pressed
     style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton" //material component style, many options to choose from
     android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
     app:cornerRadius="15dp" //corner radius, so you can adjust how much oval you want your corners to be/>
```

And you get something like this:

[image]

Comment: This looks like a great implementation but I don't understand why the button I made works perfectly in one layout, while the same identical button in the other layout doesn't.

Comment: Maybe it is your theme problem or layout problem. It could be that you simply don't have the same themes on both of the activities. You can check this in your AndroidManifest.xml file. But since MaterialComponents are a great way to design your app and don't worry about much of this stuff, just use it. It's great, simple and you have everything you need in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

See `AndroidManifest.xml` and make sure you have the same theme assigned to both of them.
The XML editor's preview also can be switched to all available themes, including custom themes.

When you provide the layout's `Context` to the XML editor alike this:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".activity.MainActivity"
```

The XML editor will pick up that theme for the preview - and there's no need to switch them.